# List all the elements of order 3 in the group $\mathbb{Z_{18}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Task:

> Consider the group $\mathbb{Z_{\large18}}$ under the operation of addition modulo $18.\;$
>   List all the elements of order $3.$

My professor said the answer was $6$ and $12$.

But isn't the answer $0,6,12\,?$

Because
$$\begin{align} \langle 6\rangle = & 6,\\ &6+6 = 12,\\&6+6+6 = 0\end{align}$$

Or is it not necessary to include $0\,?$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've identified the elements in the *subgroup* of order three:  $$\{0, 6, 12\}$$

You were asked to find the *elements* of order $3$. Only two of those elements in the subgroup have order $3$ (each of $6$ and $12$ generates the subgroup above). Indeed, $0$ is the identity element of $\mathbb Z_{18}$, and also of the subgroup above, and has order one.

Comment: So essentially, if they ask to find the number of elements of order 3. I would have to check the elements in the subgroup that have order 3?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Every group of order $3$ is cyclic, generated by either of the two elements of order three. In nonabelian groups, there may be more than one subgroup of order three. Recall how the order of an element is defined. It is the least positive integer n such that $a^n = e$, or in groups under addition, it is the least positive integer such that $na = 0$. More simply perhaps is this: the order of an element $a$ is equal to the order of the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: Makes so much sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @kero Consider another example: say we want to find elements of order 4 in $\Bbb Z_8$.  The element 2 clearly has order 4, and it generates the subgroup $\{0,2,4,6\}$, and element 6 also has order 4.  But element 4 has order 2 because $4+4=0$.

Comment: @MJD thanks for the other example. it helped a lot as well!